# Unable to detect monitor: "Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

Tags: monitor

I'm using HCL P30 laptop with 1280x800 60 Hz default resolution.  But none of the Ubuntu versions are capable of detecting my monitor.In 11.04 the resolution is 1024x768 61 Hz.
When I run xrandr command in terminal,it returns

> xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
>   Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
>   default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      1024x768       61.0*
>      800x600        61.0
>      640x480        60.0

How can I set my monitor to 1280x800  60 Hz?

Answer (score 2):

This output means that you're using the VESA drivers, meaning that Ubuntu was unable to load a driver specifically for your graphics card.

You may want to try using "Additional drivers" to see if any are offered for your graphics card.

Also, if you update your question with your graphic card's model, someone may be able to suggest a way to get this working.