# Low resolution on display-port USB-C external monitor - "Unknown Display"

Tags: nvidia, display, asus, display-resolution

I'm using a Dell XPS 9570 running Ubuntu 18.04 (with the Windows install intact).

When I plug in an external monitor, in this case a [1440p Asus Rog](https://www.asus.com/uk/Monitors/ROG_SWIFT_PG278Q/), it appears in Screen Displays as Unknown Display. The maximum the UI shows is 1024x768 (when it should be 2560x1440).

I've tried using `xrandr` to add a new resolution but when I set that the monitor complains about "out of range".

It's plugged into the USB-C port with a USB-C to Display Port cable. This setup works fine in Windows.

This all applies even when switching between graphics drivers (nouveua/nvidia-driver-390/nvidia-driver-396)

Does anyone have any thoughts?

```
$ uname -a
Linux robbie-9570-ubuntu 4.15.0-34-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 15:21:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ grep . /sys/class/drm/*/modes
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:1024x768
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:800x600
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:800x600
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:848x480
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/modes:640x480
/sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/modes:3840x2160

$ grep . /sys/class/drm/*/status
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-1/status:connected
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-2/status:disconnected
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-3/status:disconnected
/sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/status:connected

$ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 7
No EDID on bus 8
No EDID on bus 9
No EDID on bus 10
1 potential busses found: 4
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 4
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "��"
    ModelName "��"
    VendorName "SHP"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 5 of 2018
    # EDID version 1.4
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 340 190
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "false"
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 533.25 3840 3888 3920 4000 2160 2163 2168 2222 -hsync -vsync 
EndSection
```

Comment: Did you mean "when is should be 2560x1440"?

Comment: Plug in the monitor and post these commands'  output `grep . /sys/class/drm/*/modes` and `grep . /sys/class/drm/*/status`

Comment: Install edid-tools with `sudo apt install read-edid edid-decode`  and run `sudo get-edid | parse-edid` - post results.

Comment: @abu_bua done and updated the post

Comment: @abu_bua it's there, the second command

Comment: having exact same problem. Did you found some solutions ?

Comment: Sadly not, please let me know if you figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/100960/1564856) stating, in part:

> This output means that you're using the VESA drivers, meaning that Ubuntu was unable to load a driver specifically for your graphics card.
>
> You may want to try using "Additional drivers" to see if any are offered for your graphics card.

I went to "Software and Updates" --> "Additional Drivers" and noticed the driver selected for the nVidia card was and older "proprietary" one instead of the newer "proprietary and tested" driver. Changed drivers, rebooted, and that fixed the problem for me.